# override a method in the DbQueryProvider for catching exceptions from DbContext inheritor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, overriding

Using code first in Entity Framework 6, I would like to log failures to connect to the server inside my DbContext. I can override SaveChanges and catch any errors there. That part works well. However, I cannot see where to catch exceptions in the DbContext for queries run on one of my exposed sets. Can those be caught internal to DbContext? This is my callstack. Can I override any method in this stack?

```
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>>(System.Func<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>> operation) + 0xfd bytes  
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>.GetResults(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption) + 0x286 bytes 
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x45 bytes 
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>.MoveNext() + 0x45 bytes    
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo> source) + 0x139 bytes 
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.GetElementFunction.AnonymousMethod__2<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo> sequence) + 0x54 bytes   
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo> query, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression queryRoot) + 0x6c bytes    
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) + 0xc6 bytes  
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) + 0x9c bytes  
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo>(System.Linq.IQueryable<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Asi.Server.History.DBOs.LogSourceDbo,bool>> predicate) + 0x120 bytes
```

Comment: you can create and register a custom execution strategy instead of using the DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy (which is the default). EF contains an execution strategy for Azure which catches exceptions and retries the query for selected errors so it should give you a hint on how to implement this...

Comment: The plan for replacing the execution strategy almost works: I just can't see how to get the current DbContext instance inside the execution strategy.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to access the context directly from the execution strategy as it operates at a very low level. If you just want to log it to the database you may try just creating a new instance of you context to save the error to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding an implementation of `IDbConnectionInterceptor` and checking for exceptions to be not null in each overridden method.